# Laravel update hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel

I just read more documentation and issues for this problem to resolve that , but nothing work for me, i have 2 table wit this models:

```
class Month extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
    }
}

class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function months()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Month::class);
    }
}
```

I can save some data with relation ship with this sample code and that work fine:

```
$month = Month::find(1);

$lesson = new Lesson();
$lesson->title = $request->title;
$lesson->content = $request->content;
$lesson->file_url = $uploadedFilePath;
$lesson->filename = $filename;
$lesson->time = $request->time;

$month = $month->lessons()->save($lesson);
```

now I try to update some lesson fields with this code:

```
$lesson = Lesson::find($id);

$lesson->update([
    'title'    => $request->title,
    'content'  => $request->content,
    'file_url' => $uploadedFilePath,
    'filename' => $filename,
    'time'     => $request->time
]);

$month = Month::find($request->months['0']);

$lesson = Lesson::find($lesson->id);
$lesson->months()->associate($month)->save();
```

in that I try to change `month_id` column on `Lesson` table in database with for example `$month->id` value, how can I do that?

**UPDATED:**

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function month()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Month::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$lesson->update([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'content' => $request->content,
    'file_url' => $uploadedFilePath,
    'filename' => $filename,
    'time' => $request->time
]);

$month = Month::find($request->months['0']);
$lesson = Lesson::find($lesson->id);

$lesson->month()->associate($month)->save();
$lesson->update(['month_id' => $month->id]);
```

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('months', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('month_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->string('file_url');
    $table->string('filename');
    $table->string('time', 50);
    $table->foreign('month_id')->references('id')->on('months')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Are you performing both of those saves in the same controller at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,  the name of method `months()` should be renamed to `month` because it's returning single month not multiple months.

Secondly, If your `Lesson` has a field called `month_id` then its far simpler than you are thinking about. We can just change these two lines:

```
$lesson = Lesson::find($lesson->id);
$lesson->months()->associate($month)->save();
```

To the following line:

`$lesson->update(['month_id' => $month->id);`

It should update the `month_id` of your `$lesson` to the `$month->id`

Comment: could you check my updated post? it doent for for me